Why do we define $ A(x, y)=(a x+b y, c x+d y) $ in complex analysis?

Remark I.5.2 For an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map
$$
A: \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}
$$
the following four statements are equivalent:
(1) There exists a complex number $l$ with $A z=l z$.
(2) $A$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear.
(3) $A(\mathrm{i})=\mathrm{i} A(1)$.
(4) The matrix with respect to the canonical basis $1(=(1,0))$ and $\mathrm{i}(=(0,1))$ has the special form
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\alpha & -\beta \\
\beta & \alpha
\end{array}\right) \quad(\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}) .
$$
Proof. The statements (1), (2) and (3) are trivially equivalent. It remains to prove the equivalence of (1) and (4).
First we recall how to introduce the matrix corresponding to a linear map
$$
A: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2
$$Since $A$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear, we have
$$
A(x, y)=(a x+b y, c x+d y)
$$
with certain real numbers $a, b, c, d$. The corresponding matrix is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right) .
$$
If one sets $A(x, y)=:(u, v)$, then this equation simply can be written as matrix multiplication
$$
\binom{u}{v}=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right)\binom{x}{y} .
$$
In doing this, we identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ via the isomorphism
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{C} & \sim \mathbb{R}^2 \\
x+\mathrm{i} y & \longmapsto\binom{x}{y} .
\end{aligned}
$$

I have a question about $$A(x, y)=(a x+b y, c x+d y)
$$
Why it is specifically $(a x+b y, c x+d y)$ why not $(ax+dy,by+cx)$ or any of the other nine ways we can arrange these four terms on $(u,v)$?

Note that $a,b,c,d$ have not been defined up until the formula for $A(x,y)$. So we can define $b$ to be the coefficient of $y$ in the first component, and similarly for $c,d$.

Any linear map does look like $(ax+by,cx+dy)$. The variable names are upto you, you can take $(dx+ay,bx+cy)$ or anything else you wish.
Once you do that, say $A(x,y)=(ax+by,cx+dy)$, then note that by matrix multiplication,
$$A\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}{ax+by}\\{cx+dy}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}{x}\\{y}\end{pmatrix}$$
This does not work if you take any other matrix involving $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.
Hope this helps. :)
